# php multiple inputs for strpos function?

Tags: php

i try to create a script which auto add brands to my products but i need a solution to check over 100 brands not one :/ so in this case i have "$brand = 'Ray Ban';" but i need to replace it with something like "$brand = 'Ray Ban, Adidas, Nike';" anyone know how i can handle that?

```
  function atkp_product_updated_callback2($product_id) {
        require_once  ATKP_PLUGIN_DIR.'/includes/atkp_product.php';
        /* Get Woocommerce Product ID*/
        $woo_product = atkp_product::get_woo_product($product_id);
        $woocommerce_product_id = $woo_product->ID;

        $name = ATKPTools::get_post_setting( $product_id, ATKP_PRODUCT_POSTTYPE.'_title');
      /* Get Brand List */
        $brand = 'Ray Ban';
      /* Check if brandname in product name */
        $brandchecker = strpos($name, $brand);
        if ($brandchecker === false) {
            /* if try another */
        } else {
            /* if true add to brand*/
             ATKPTools::check_taxonomy($woocommerce_product_id, 'store', $brand); /* Add to the Woocommerce Store Taxonmy */
        }
    }
add_action('atkp_product_updated', 'atkp_product_updated_callback2');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [preg_match_all()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) and the or operator in the regex you can search for multiple needles if you have `$brands` as an array like this:

```
<?php
$brands = ["Ray Ban", "Adidas", "Mercedes"];

function hasBrands($brands, $heystack) {
   $regex = '('.implode('|', $brands).')';
   $success = preg_match_all($regex, $heystack, $matches);
    //var_dump($success);
   return $success;
}

echo hasBrands($brands, "Lorem Ray Ban and Adidas but not BMW") . "<br>";
echo hasBrands($brands, "but not BMW") . "<br>";
echo hasBrands($brands, "Adidas or Puma?") . "<br>";

// output:
// 2
// 0
// 1
```

If you need the matching brands, just return $matches from the function (or an empty array if nothing was found):

```
function getBrands($brands, $heystack) {
   $regex = '('.implode('|', $brands).')';
   $success = preg_match_all($regex, $heystack, $matches);
   return $success ? $matches[0] : [];
}

var_dump(getBrands($brands, "Lorem Ray Ban and Mercedes are in this string"));

// output:
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(7) "Ray Ban"
  [1]=>
  string(8) "Mercedes"
}
```

*ADDENDUM*:
If you want only the first match, access it via [0] from the returned array from getBrands. You should check first that there actually was an item found.

```
$foundBrands = getBrands($brands, "Lorem Adidas Mercedes BMW");
if(!empty($foundBrands)) {
    $firstBrand = $foundBrands[0];
} else {
    $firstBrand = null;
    echo "no brand found!";
}

echo $firstBrand; // Adidas
```

Comment: sorry i am very new in php... so can you please explain me how i can save only the first array in a string? like  output:"array(1) { [0]=> string(6) "adidas" }"

Comment: $brand = var_dump(getBrands($brands, $name)[0]);

Comment: that in $brand only the first result is?

Comment: `$firstBrand = getBrands($brands, $searchString)[0];` - with `[0]` you access the first item in the array. You should check first that there _is something_ in the array.

Comment: Okay Thanks you!